# Make Graphics Card process like an additional CPU to my program

Tags: hardware, cpu, utilization

So is it possible to make the graphics card act like an additional CPU in my program,  calculating other things beside graphical content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Nvidia card then you want to look at [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html).  For ATI you want to look at [ATI Stream](http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/TECHNOLOGIES/STREAM-TECHNOLOGY/Pages/stream-technology.aspx).  There are other technologies that provide a more cross-platform approach, for example [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU), etc.